# Python Server on different IP address

Tags: python, webserver

So I have a web server that I can run using python, but I have a question. Can I change the IP address where the server runs the only one I can get to work is 127.0.0.1 which is the localhost address? I have already tried with no luck I want to use a unused one on my network.

Here's the code:

```
import sys
import BaseHTTPServer
from SimpleHTTPServer import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
HandlerClass = SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
ServerClass = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer
Protocol = "HTTP/1.0"
if sys.argv[1:]:
      port = int(sys.argv[1])
else:
      port = 8000
server_address = ('127.0.0.1', port)
HandlerClass.protocol_version = Protocol
httpd = ServerClass(server_address, HandlerClass) 
sa = httpd.socket.getsockname()
print "Running server on", sa[0], "port", sa[1], "..."
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use addresses that are bound to a network interface on the computer. You cannot use random addresses picked out of thin air.

Comment: is there any way module or something along those lines i could use do do this?

Comment: Why don't you know what addresses are bound on the machine?

Comment: i do but i already use that ip address for something else but want to use a diffrent one

Comment: Then bind another address to an interface. Or pick a different port.

Comment: well i want to be able to access it on another computer but i cant with 127.0.0.1 address and when i try setting it as the adress of the computer 192.168.254.142 it doesnt work

Comment: Or if you want to bind the address to a NIC on the fly at program start up, make a syscall to `ip addr add 192.168.254.142 dev ethXYZ`, being `ethXYZ` the desired NIC.